# Await inside if statement with Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, async-await

#### Problem

I'm writing a [simple Express app](https://github.com/DonaldKellett/Linux-Rocks) to practice on my Node.js and Docker skills and currently have the following server-side code:

```js
// server.js
'use strict'
const fs = require('fs').promises
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const ejs = require('ejs')
const app = express()
const port = 80

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.use('/assets', express.static('/srv/opt/Linux-Rocks/assets'))
app.use('/images', express.static('/srv/opt/Linux-Rocks/images'))

app.route(/^\/(register)?$/)
  .get(async (req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' })
    res.write(await fs.readFile('/srv/opt/Linux-Rocks/index.html'))
    res.end()
  })
  // FIXME: This hangs the connection indefinitely, don't know why
  .post(async (req, res) => {
    if (typeof req.body['email'] !== 'string') {
      res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' })
      let template = await fs.readFile('/srv/opt/Linux-Rocks/register.ejs', { encoding: 'utf8' })
      res.write(ejs.render(template, { title: 'TODO', description: 'TODO', contentBody: '<p>TODO</p>' }))
      res.end()
    } else {
      // TODO
    }
  })

app.get('/license', async (req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' })
  res.write(await fs.readFile('/srv/opt/Linux-Rocks/LICENSE'))
  res.end()
})

app.listen(port)
```

When I get the web server up and running (let's call it `linux-rocks.com`) and visit `http://linux-rocks.com/` (or `http://linux-rocks.com/register`), the webpage loads immediately as expected. However, when I send a POST request to the same endpoint (`/` / `/register`), regardless of whether or not I include the `email` field in the POST data, the connection hangs indefinitely. I've peered inside the (Docker container running the) web server by starting a shell session within and manually running `npm start` (which starts the server at `server.js`) but do not see any errors or warnings emitted after a POST request to either endpoint so the hanging connection is unlikely due to an error or promise rejection crashing the server.

What might be the problem in the POST handler within my server that's causing the hanging connection? I suspect it probably has something to do with my (incorrect) use of `async`/`await` within an `if` conditional.

#### What I tried

I spent at least an hour or two Googling for related tutorials and issues along the lines of "async/await with if statement in nodejs" but none of the search results quite seem to match the exact issue I'm facing, e.g. many `async`/`await` examples involving `if` statements I found usually have only one line in their bodies or have the `await` right before the `if` statement (and not inside).

#### To reproduce

My current project code with instructions on how to run the web server can be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/DonaldKellett/Linux-Rocks).

Comment: What happens when you try to write a response in the `else` part of the post ? Does it show up ?

Comment: Note that generally most parsers will parse **everything** in `req.body` as a string. Therefore your `if` never gets executed. It hangs because you do nothing in your `else`

Comment: try to add in the `else`: `res.send('ok');` and see if it returns. My guess is that the requests hangs for a long time (until timeout is reached - which could be a few minutes or even longer) because the `if` is never executed. If this assumption is correct, try to print teh body before the condition and see why it's happening.

Comment: @siebetman That was it - I was triggering the `else` part of the branch when I thought it was supposed to trigger the `if` part (though with a catch). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As some of the comments to my question have mentioned, the reason I was encountering the hang was because I triggered the `else` part of the branch with an empty email address (which appears as an empty string in the `email` field of the POST data). I thought I was triggering the `if` branch by changing the `id` of the HTML tag for the email field to something different (e.g. `id="haha"`) before submitting the form, but then I just realized that I should be changing the `name` field instead (which I finally did, and managed to trigger the `if` branch with the expected results).